# Mongodb installation on Linux

Tags: mongodb

I installed mongodb version 2.6 on redhat linux 6 with the `yum` utility.

The installation creates a user mongod (without home directory). This user is the owner of the `mongod.conf` file and the mongod process as well.
The `mongod` service on linux must be started with the root user.

Why had not the installer created a mongo user so that the root would not be required to start the service?

Comment: While root is necessary to start the service, the unit script runs the service as the mongodb user. You don't want an unprivileged user to be able to start and stop services, do you?

Comment: yes, you are right, I will manage the mongo service as root user. Thanks for your answer